# How does the Install Port appear when a girl becomes a Reyvateil?

Tags: ar-tonelico

So 3rd Generation Reyvateils are originally born as humans but if their mother was a Reyvateil they may develop into one later in life.

From my understanding all Reyvateil have an install port surrounded by a tattoo and since Gathnode Crystals and Life Extending Agents are Physical Objects that get inserted into a Reyvateil with both being somewhat painful this would make it into a hole right?

But i can't imagine how this hole appears. does the skin just open up one day? does a Reyvateil have to go under some procedure to have it made (ie. when they get their first Life Extending Agent) or is it a gradual process?

Comment: The Install Port isn't a hole: it's a mark on the skin that has the purpose of "dissolving" into waves any crystals made from a Parameno or Grathnode base that enter in contact with it so the Reyvateil can absorb them.

Comment: If it dissolves into waves then how does the Life Extending Agent hurt so much during insertions? i recall Aurica or Lyner commenting on the size of it but if it dissolves then size shouldn't matter

Comment: Because these waves enter in contact with her H-Wave component to extend her life, and having foreign waves enter their bodies like that causes a tremendous pain. It's somewhat like having a micro-nuclear meltdown taking place on their bodies, as waves are what make up everything in the world. Check this up for more details on it: http://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/ARM_Backup/Ar_Portal_translation/Toukousphere/Issue_55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the data the [Exa_Pico](http://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/Reyvateil#cite_note-11) Wikia gathered form the agmes and the [Toukoushpere](http://artonelico.wikia.com/wiki/ARM_Backup/Ar_Portal_translation/Toukousphere) (a segment where characters answered questions sent from users), it seems to be concluded that, after a server mistakenly recognizes a 3rd generation human as a Reyvateil, it begins a long process of correcting what it sees as a somehow ignored Reyvateil that ended up with irregular development, and starts using this human's memories ands senses to develop a soulspace.

The process of developing this soulspace takes about ten days, in which the human enters a comatose state. At the end of the process, the human will have awakened as a Reyvateil, with a Install Port appearing in their body.

So, the Insatll Port appears automatically, after a girl awakens as a Reyvateil.

Unfortunatley, it is not clear of the Install Port is a hole, but from the way it is depicted, the symbol may work as a kind of portal for specific materials (data crystals).